# PHP Can't read media:content attribute

Tags: php, rss

I use the following PHP code to parse RSS feed into HTML:

```
function get_rss_feed_as_html($feed_url, $max_item_cnt = 10, $show_date = true, $show_description = true, $max_words = 0, $cache_timeout = 7200, $cache_prefix = "/tmp/rss2html-")
    {
    $result = "";
    $rss = new DOMDocument();
    $cache_file = $cache_prefix . md5($feed_url);

    if ($cache_timeout > 0 &&
        is_file($cache_file) &&
        (filemtime($cache_file) + $cache_timeout > time())) {
            $rss->load($cache_file);
    } else {
        $rss->load($feed_url);
        if ($cache_timeout > 0) {
            $rss->save($cache_file);
        }
    }

    $feed = array();
    foreach ($rss->getElementsByTagName('entry') as $node) {
        
        $item = array (
            'title' => $node->getElementsByTagName('title')->item(0)->nodeValue,
            'desc' => $node->getElementsByTagName('content ')->item(0)->nodeValue,
            'content' => $node->getElementsByTagName('content')->item(0)->nodeValue,
            'link' => $node->getElementsByTagName('link')->item(0)->getAttribute('href'),
            'date' => $node->getElementsByTagName('updated')->item(0)->nodeValue,
            'media' => $node->getElementsByTagName('media:content')->item(0)->getAttribute('url'),
        );
        $content = $node->getElementsByTagName('encoded');
        if ($content->length > 0) {
            $item['content'] = $content->item(0)->nodeValue;
        }
        array_push($feed, $item);
    }

    if ($max_item_cnt > count($feed)) {
        $max_item_cnt = count($feed);
    }
    $result .= '<div class="bw-feedly-list">';
    for ($x=0;$x<$max_item_cnt;$x++) {
        $title = str_replace(' & ', ' &amp; ', $feed[$x]['title']);
        $link = $feed[$x]['link'];
        $result .= '<div class="bw-feedly-item-col">';
        $result .= '<a class="bw-feedly-item" href="'.$link.'" title="'.$title.'" target="_blank">';
        if ($show_date) {
            $date = date('F d, Y', strtotime($feed[$x]['date']));
            $result .= '<div class="bw-feedly-date">'.$date.'</div>';
        }
        
        $result .= '<strong class="bw-feedly-title">'.$title.'</strong>';
        
        if ($show_description) {
            $result .= '<div class="bw-feedly-row">';
            $result .= '<div class="bw-feedly-summary-col">';
            
            $description = $feed[$x]['content'];
            $content = $feed[$x]['content'];

            // no html tags
            $description = strip_tags(preg_replace('/(<(script|style)\b[^>]*>).*?(<\/\2>)/s', "$1$3", $description), '');
            // whether cut by number of words
            if ($max_words > 0) {
                $arr = explode(' ', $description);
                if ($max_words < count($arr)) {
                    $description = '';
                    $w_cnt = 0;
                    foreach($arr as $w) {
                        $description .= $w . ' ';
                        $w_cnt = $w_cnt + 1;
                        if ($w_cnt == $max_words) {
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    $description .= " ...";
                }
            }
            
            $result .= '<div class="feed-description">' . $description . '</div>';
            
            $media = $feed[$x]['media'];
            
            // add img if it exists
            //if ($media !== '') {
                $result .= '<div class="bw-feedly-image-col">';
                $result .= '<div class="bw-feedly-image-wrap" style="background-image: url('. $media .');">';
                $result .= '<img class="bw-feedly-image" src="'. $media .'">';
                $result .= '</div></div>';
            //}
            
            $result .= '</div></div>';
        }
        $result .= '</div>';
    }
    $result .= '</a></div>';
    return $result;
}
```

It works fine, except retrieving the right media (URL) attribute:

```
'media' => $node->getElementsByTagName('media:content')->item(0)->getAttribute('url'),
```

The following error occures:
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getAttribute() on null in

Here I can access the attribute without any issue..

```
'link' => $node->getElementsByTagName('link')->item(0)->getAttribute('href')
```

Not all entries in the XML feed has a media element, but any null check does not change a thing.

I also tried the this piece of code, I guess I am close, but still without success.
Its printing for all entries 'content is null'..

```
 if($node->getElementsByTagNameNS('http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/', 'content')->length > 0){
        $image = $node->getElementsByTagNameNS('http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/', 'content')->item(0)->getAttribute('url');
    } else {
    
        echo '<p>content is null</p>';
    }
```

xPath expressions aren't helping me neither.

```
$xpath = new DOMXpath($rss);
$xpath->registerNamespace('m', 'http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/');

foreach ($xpath->evaluate('//entry') as $item) 
{
    $media = $xpath->evaluate('string(m:content/@url)', $item);
    echo '<p> MEDIA ITEM: '.$media.'</p>';
}
```

Here a part of the XML.

```
    <entry>
     <id>tag:04ac51c7-b707-43cc-8a73-c482da986a27</id>
     <title type="html">Lorem Ipsum</title>
     <published>2020-09-28T19:36:26Z</published>
     <updated>2020-09-28T06:01:22Z</updated>
     <link rel="alternate" href="https://www.lipsum.com/" type="text/html"/>
     <content type="html">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum. ...</content>
     <author>
     <name/>
     </author>
     <media:content medium="image" url="https://picsum.photos/200/300"/>
     <source>
     <id>tag:04ac51c7-b707-43cc-8a73-c482da986a27</id>
     <title type="html">Lorum ipsum</title>
     <link rel="alternate" type="text/html" href="https://www.lipsum.com/"/>
     <updated>2020-09-28T06:01:22Z</updated>
     </source>
    </entry>
    <entry>
```

What is the trick here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it all working, hopefully it will help someone else.

```
    $image = '';
    if($node->getElementsByTagNameNS('http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/', 'content')->length > 0){
        $image = $node->getElementsByTagNameNS('http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/', 'content')->item(0)->getAttribute('url');
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

It should work with the getElementsByTagNameNS function.

You should be able to use getElementsByTagName without the namespace tag. So leave out 'media'.

```
$node->getElementsByTagName('content')->item(0)->getAttribute('url')
```

this will conflict if you have multiple namespaces with content though.

Comment: I thought so as well, but in this case the 'Call to a member function getAttribute() on null' error too. :( (thanks for your reply anyway)

Comment: I have another 'content' element in the XML btw. so that won't work, I will add a part of the XML feed.